# On a much weaker version of the Normal conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, pr.probability, real-analysis

I would like to ask you about the following question. It is conjectured that every algebraic irrational number is normal (absolutely normal). I know the result by Bugeaud and Adamczewski about the non-linearity of the complexity function. Unfortunately, this was not enough to solve the question I have in mind. But, my question is the following:

*Any algebraic irrational number contains at least one 0 in its expansion in basis $b$ for all $b\geq 2$ sufficiently large (or at least for $b$ in the form $10^s$, for every $s$ sufficiently large)?*

Comment: Do you really mean base $b$ rather than $b$-adic?

Comment: @RobertIsrael thanks!

Comment: Are you asking whether this assertion has been proved? To my knowledge, it has not.

Comment: Do you know this article by Michel Waldschmidt: https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.4034? Look at Conjecture 1.1.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not known whether, say, $\sqrt{2}$ contains infinitely many zeros in its decimal expansion. If not, you could very easily make a quadratic irrational with no zeros past the decimal point.